# SimpleHTTPServer - Serving Big Files

Tags: python, http, simplehttpserver

i'm using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` for a small project. The file index.html references some videos.
    `<video><source src="big_buck_bunny_480p_stereo.ogg"></video>`
This File has a size of 159 MB. When I try to download it, SimpleHTTPServer throws some error messages instead of my video.

```
Marc-Laptop - - [23/Sep/2012 18:18:29] "GET /big_buck_bunny_480p_stereo.ogg HTTP
/1.1" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.4.38', 51152)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:Program Files (x86)PythonlibSocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle
_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:Program Files (x86)PythonlibSocketServer.py", line 310, in process
_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:Program Files (x86)PythonlibSocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_
request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:Program Files (x86)PythonlibSocketServer.py", line 640, in __init_
_
    self.finish()
  File "C:Program Files (x86)PythonlibSocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "C:Program Files (x86)Pythonlibsocket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10054] Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen

----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Try to run the server in an English locale -- English error messages are usually easier to find on search engines.

Comment: Well, why would you stream static content through Python? First, I would suggest you use HTTP server like NGINX or Apache for that task. Second, I think that what might be happening is that you try to load the whole file in memory and then stream it, which fails - instead see if you could first send the headers for it's size, then output it block by block so that it does not get loaded in memory at all.

Comment: @Veseliq Why *not* use Python for static content? A web-server is a web-server. (I don't doubt the idea of the whole file being slurped, but this is orthogonal to Python or some other server.)

Comment: As you see, i did not code one line. Just using, what is given by python. Inside a http-connection, the client can request just a part of a file (range). I thought, SimpleHTTPServer would be able to handle this. In fact, i only need a minimal http-server, which delivers some (possibly big) files to the clients (LAN). Maybe someone knows an alternative (and easy to use) solution in python.

Comment: pst, I agree, what I meant is that both Apache and NGINX for example are highly optimized to server static content, thus often (especially NGINX) preferred way for that task. I have no experience with SimpleHTTPServer, it might have build-in method for handling file downloads, but if it lacks such functionality, I'd go with second server for that task, handling only the rest of the requests with python. If not - as I stated, you should be able to first flush the headers to the browser (length, type, etc), then start outputting the file few bytes at a time (eg 1024). Otherwise its overkill.

Answer (score 4):

simpleHTTPServer is trying to buffer everything and indeed will explode for the lack of memory. It is better to do it asynchronously but simpleHTTPServer doesn't know how to do that. Check that [thread](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/259148-simple-http-server-based-on-asyncoreasynchat/). Someone proposed a modified version of simpleHTTPserver: [SimpleAsyncHTTPServer.py](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=SimpleAsyncHTTPServer.py)

Comment: Link to [SimpleAsyncHTTPServer.py](https://github.com/cvan/waddle/blob/master/SimpleAsyncHTTPServer.py)

Comment: Is there a similar solution for python3?